# Почему клиент не получает ответ?

Tags: java, servlet, клиент-сервер, jstl, сервлеты

С сервера не приходит ответ, в чем может быть проблема? При этом запрос он видит.

Сервер:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

       String val = request.getParameter("val");
        Double num = Double.parseDouble(val);


        if (num > 0 && num <9 ){
            List<Employee> empList = new ArrayList<Employee>();
            Employee emp1 = new Employee();
            emp1.setId(1); emp1.setName("Pasha");emp1.setRole("Developer");
            Employee emp2 = new Employee();
            emp2.setId(2); emp2.setName("Masha");emp2.setRole("Manager");
            empList.add(emp1);empList.add(emp2);
            request.setAttribute("empList", empList);
        request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").forward(request,response);
```

Клиент:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
    <tr><th>ID</th><th>Name</th><th>Role</th></tr>
    <c:forEach items="${requestScope.empList}" var="emp">
        <tr><td><c:out value="${emp.id}"></c:out></td>
            <td><c:out value="${emp.name}"></c:out></td>
            <td><c:out value="${emp.role}"></c:out></td></tr>
    </c:forEach>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Он у вас пустую таблицу выдаёт?

Comment: Какая ошибка отображается?

Comment: @ЕвгенийГлушков, да выдает пустую таблицу с наименованием полей, Roman, ошибок нет.

Answer (score 1):

может так попробовать:

```
<c:forEach items="${empList}" var="emp">
<jsp:useBean id="emp" scope="page" type="package from class.Employee"/>
```

дальше как было

кстати c:out не требует закрывающего тега

```
<c:out value="${emp.id}"/>
```